# No Reverse Match with Django Auth Views

Tags: python, django

I created a custom User model following the example in the Django documentation, now I'm trying to use Django auth views but I keep getting `NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/`

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is the url conf:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html',
        'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/accounts/login'}),
    url(r'^$', home, name="home"),    
    ]
```

And I have this line in my template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

This is incorrect. We put the name given to the url here instead of the location of the view.

Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url. You need to provide a name for login like you have for home and then use that.

Correct way is:
urls.py ->

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html','authentication_form': LoginForm}, name="login") ,
```

template ->

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made the suggested change but I'm still getting the same error during template rendering

Comment: No way. Can you please add the traceback and any other relevant information.

Comment: 'Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
'

Comment: the urls file you have shared here, when it is added to the main urls file, did you happen to provide it a namespace? if so, then you need to use the 'namespace:name' format. Please refer the docs, or share more code

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the problem. It was namespaced. I really do appreciate your help

Comment: Stick around. I'm sure I'll run into some more trouble before the end of the night

Comment: Lol, refer to the docs, they will guide you better than SO. trust me